# What is the best approach to make my HTML code responsive for mobile with minimal amount of re-writing code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, responsive

sorry if this is a fairly vague question, I have a grid with two rows ontop of one another with content expanding below either of the two rows when the panel is clicked. This works fine on desktop and tablet sized devices but for mobile I'd like the panels to span vertically, with the expanding content opening directly beneath each panel. Any pointers on a starting point for this would be great, I know I can use media queries but really unsure how to structure my code to make it a reality.

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/a3e6514r/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h2>Expanding Grid</h2>
      <p>Click on the boxes below:</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b1');">
        <img src="./Icons/Banking.svg" />
        <p>Banking</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b2');">
        <img src="./Icons/Regtech.svg" />
        <p>RegTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b3');">
        <img src="./Icons/InsurTech.svg" />
        <p>InsurTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b4');">
        <img src="./Icons/Lending.svg" />
        <p>Lending</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Full-width columns: (hidden by default) -->
    <div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h3>Banking</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b2" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>RegTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b3" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>InsurTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b4" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Lending</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b5');">
        <img src="./Icons/Accounting.svg" />
        <p>Accounting</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b6');">
        <img src="./Icons/Payments.svg" />
        <p>Payments</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b7');">
        <img src="./Icons/Quote.svg" />
        <p>Quote Aggregators</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b8');">
        <img src="./Icons/WealthTech.svg" />
        <p>WealthTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="b5" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Accounting</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b6" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Payments</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b7" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Quote</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b8" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>WealthTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    function openTab(tabName) {
      var i, x;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName('containerTab');
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Get all the tabs into a collection
    // (don't use .getElementsByClassName()!)
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.column');

    // Set up a click event handler on each of the tabs
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // Loop over all the tabs and remove the active class
        tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
          tab.classList.remove('active-column');
        });

        // Set the background of the clicked tab
        this.classList.add('active-column');
      });
    });
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.active-column {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the container tab */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Get busy with the CSS, there's @media that you can set for when the screen size is below e.g. 900px width and change your element sizing/etc.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: So, i've used media queries to align the tiles as I want when the screen width is below 405px - but is there a way to update the positioning of the supporting text (in this case various `divs`) using the media query? Fiddle updated here:

https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/a3e6514r/4/

Comment: Yes you can! You would insert within that @media wrap your new CSS to change the elements you want. Add as much as you want or little to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this code to your css:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .column{
    width:100%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can a @media in css to make it so it responds really well on mobile devices

Comment: So, i've used media queries to align the tiles as I want when the screen width is below 405px - but is there a way to update the positioning of the supporting text (in this case various `divs`) using the media query? Fiddle updated here:

https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/a3e6514r/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you want my advice, you should use bootstrap for a base of your css. It will really help you when you'll organise your page. There is a lot of good documentation in their. You only need to add classes in your elements. It's really easy to use.

link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Your page is separated by 12 pieces. You can say, if my page is large, take 3/12 of the space for each elements. If the page is medium size, take the half of the page and if it's small, take all the horizontal space. So in my class, I'll write `class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12"`. I'm sorry if it's not clear. But for real it's really simple.

Comment: Bootstrap really would be ideal Adam but sadly it's a small addition to a site currently without BS so I can't really add it now! 

So, i've used media queries to align the tiles as I want when the screen width is below 405px - but is there a way to update the positioning of the supporting text (in this case various `divs`) using the media query? Fiddle updated here:

https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/a3e6514r/4/